# How to view/edit extended properties of SQL Table in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata, bcs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [Edit SQL Extended Properties in SharePoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972963/edit-sql-extended-properties-in-sharepoint-2010)

Hi everyone,

I know how to view/edit table data from an external SQL (non SharePoint) database from my SharePoint 2010 web front end.

However, I also want to view/edit the **extended properties** (metadata) as well.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be staying away from the SharePoint database (especially edit) as it is not supported?

Comment: The OP doesn't make clear if he's wanting to display results from a SharePoint SQL Database or another SQL database.

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831954/how-to-edit-sql-extended-properties-in-sharepoint

Comment: I'm going to check out those links...

Comment: for clarification, i want to create an external connection to a SQL Database outside of SharePoint, and view the extended properties of a SQL Table and be able to edit the properties in SharePoint directly without having to do it in SQL. I'm trying to figure out ways to do this without having to write code. I might need to write code, who knows.

Comment: Ryan, the 'this guide' link does not work.

Comment: The both work for me - just tried now.

Answer (score 2):

You don't make clear if you are wanting to access a SharePoint Database (not supported as NLV say) or a.n.other database via SharePoint.

I am assuming the latter.

There are lots of table viewer/editor web parts but I don't know of any that let you work with metadata so you're probably going to have to develop your own - [this guide](http://vspug.com/sam/2007/12/08/test/) and [this one](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040219.htm) are for a viewer but should give you a head start.

Comment: For clarification, I want to create an external connection, via webpart or any other method, where I can view the extended properties of a SQL table from a database outside of SharePoint.