# Edit SQL Extended Properties in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, extended-properties

How can I edit extended properties of a table in SharePoint 2010?

So far, I'm thinking there's nothing 'out-the-box' that does this. So, I'm assuming this means that I will have to make a custom web-part that extracts the extended properties of a table, then allows me to edit that, and then after editing is complete, the webpart updates the extended properties in SQL.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do this without using code (out the box features or something) OR  if this is the ONLY  way to do it.

Comment: As with your cross-post on SharePoint Overflow, please elaborate on what you mean by "Extended Properties" of a table - do you mean a Lists settings & columns? Or do you mean a SQL table, bearing in mind it is an unsupported practice to directly interact with the SQL Databases associated with SharePoint.

Comment: Extended Properties of a SQL table. Right-click on table, go to properties, then go to extended properties, and type in information I want to extract.

Comment: At this point, I've figured out how to insert these extended properties into a separate table. I want to know how SharePoint 2010 can "run" a query and extract the extended properties mentioned earlier. I'm thinking I need a custom web part, right???

Answer (score 0):

Once these properties are in a separate table, create an external content type based on that list.  You can then create an external table based on that content type and edit the data stored in that SQL Server table.